# Laravel where complicated statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to make a complicated statement, i explain:

(Sorry for my english i'm french)

I have make a ecommerce website with laravel, all is working very well, but i have add a pricepallet table with this struct:

id
pricepallet
dep_first
dep_end

Dep first containt the postal code of the warehouse and dep_end contain the postal code of my customer; i have save this postal code in session.

I want to have the pricepallet data in term of the postal code in my session i have write this code but i dont know how to make the statement:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{  
    $duplicata = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) use ($request) {
        return $cartItem->id == $request->product_id;
    });

    if ($duplicata->isNotEmpty()) {
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }

    $product = Product::find($request->product_id);

    $cptransport = Session::get('cp');
    $cp = substr($cptransport, 0, -3);

    $transport = Pricepallet::where('dep_end', $cp);
    
    Cart::add($product->id, $product->title, 1, $product->price)
        ->associate('App\Product');

    return redirect()->route('product.index');

}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Pls try this: $transports = Pricepallet::where('dep_end', $cp)->get();

Comment: @KevinBui its work in my dd command i can view all the pallet with the price, if i want to show in my cart for exemple pallet1, what is the code ? its my dd: https://i.imgur.com/k5fCqoW.png thank a lot

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems that you want to get the first record, pls try this:

```
$transport = Pricepallet::where('dep_end', $cp)->firstOrFail();

$pallet1 = $transport->pallet1;
```

Comment: Yes thinks, but i want to get the pallet1 data its 200 i want to store this data in a variable. :)

Comment: on more question if have to line in my table with two pricepallet1 what is the statement for get the lowest price if i have two line with two different price. Thx